# Importing Excel Data to Datatable By converting Cell values to string format

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, oledb, c#-3.0

I am trying to read excel file to a data table, and I am getting the data successfully, but the decimal values are getting truncated on reading data to data table

So, if I have a cell value as 64.00, I am the getting 64 instead of 64.00 in data table.

I tried formatting the excel cell value as Text but didn't worked.

Below is the code that I am working on.

```
 public static DataTable GetDataTableFromCsv(string path, bool 
 isFirstRowHeader)
    {
        string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";

        string pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);

        string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
                  @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
                  ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but you might try building the datatable with the columns and data types instead of allowing the adapter to generate it. If you make that column a decimal type then it might work.

Comment: [Schema.ini](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Steve, that works with the Jet provider on Excel?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes, It is the underlying TextDriver that exploits the schema.ini file. Of course using a normal text file (CSV or fixed format) not a binary excel file

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do so already, you can try to get the contents of the cell with Worksheet.Cell[x,y].Text
That forces the output into a string literal, so it skips truncation wile reading